# How to save the state of a button in AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android, button

I am new at programing in Java and I am taking a course of Android application. I am building a button inside an activity. But when I exit the activity, the button changes to it's original state. I know I am not doing anything to save its state, but how do I do it?

Here is the xml file (only the button part):

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Catch"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="toggleCatch" />
```

And here is toggleCatch:

```
private boolean isCaught = false;    
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void toggleCatch(View view) {
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        if (isCaught) {
            button.setText("Catch");
            isCaught = false;
        } else {
            button.setText("Release");
            isCaught = true;
        }
    }
```

What could I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

you should store the data that indicate on it state in some place: 
1. SQLlite
2. Server
3. SharedPreference

and then when you create the activity you set the state of the btn based on the data you loaded.

if you do it just for practice, I believe that the sharepreference will be just fine.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

to store any data locally in the sharedPreference:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("SOME_NAME_FOR_YOUR_VARIABLE_EX_BTN_STATE", trueOrFalse);
editor.commit();
```

to get the saved data:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean stateBtn = sharedPref.getBoolean("SOME_NAME_FOR_YOUR_VARIABLE_EX_BTN_STATE", defaultValueForExTrue);
```

sharedPref.getBoolean can be used also for sharedPref.getString, sharedPref.getInt Etc..

hope that helped..
My recommendation for you is to read about the subjects above.(SQLlite, SharedPreference)

Comment: Should I do `editor.putBoolean("Catch", false);` and `editor.putBoolean("Release", false);` ? Or just one and if it is false I write caught, else release? @Shai Epstein

Comment: I get `Cannot resolve method 'getActivity' in 'PokemonActivity'` How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save button state in persistent storage; there are several types of persistent storage that Android supports, like `SharedPreference`, DataBase, internal/external storage File... The most appropriate for your question is the [`SharedPreference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) as it stores small data.

To achieve that in your code sample

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PREFS_NAME";
public static final String BUTTON_STATUS = "status";

private boolean isCaught = false;    
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
public void toggleCatch(View view) {
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    if (isCaught) {
        button.setText("Catch");
        isCaught = false;
    } else {
        button.setText("Release");
        isCaught = true;
    }

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(BUTTON_STATUS, isCaught);
    editor.apply();

}
```

And you need to retrieve the value again from the shared preference when the app is launched, so in your activity onCreate() method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    isCaught = prefs.getBoolean(BUTTON_STATUS, false);  

    if (isCaught) {
        button.setText("Release");
    } else {
        button.setText("Catch");
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not working. When I exit the activity, it shows Catch againg

Comment: @Joaquin I updated the answer, just swapped the "Release" and "Catch" strings when the activity is launched .. good luck in it

Comment: Now when I exit the activity with the button set on Catch, and re enter it, it flags Release. The app is supposed to be a Pokedex, so the main activity is all the pokemon, and when you click on a pokemon, it shows you things about it, plus the catch/release button.

Comment: I forgot to tag you in the previous comment @Zain

Comment: @Joaquin so when you leave the button at Catch and leave the activity you want to get it at Catch .. the same for Release right?

Comment: can you please answer me. If you want, I can give you a copy of my code, but I really cant put my head on an answer.

Comment: @Joaquin please check updated answer, just updated the condition within the `onCreate()` method, hope it works now